# colorbox lightbox not running

Tags: lightbox, colorbox

i have been using colorbox lightbox(slideshow) but the problem is whenever i click on the image i get "settings is undefined". which setting is it talking about. i am confused. i tried to change the settings but i can't find what to change. the settings it showed was

```
if (settings.slideshow && $related[1]) {
            start = function () {
                $slideshow
                    .text(settings.slideshowStop)
                    .unbind(click)
                    .bind(event_complete, function () {
                        if (index < $related.length - 1 || settings.loop) {
                            timeOut = setTimeout(publicMethod.next, settings.slideshowSpeed);
                        }
                    })
                    .bind(event_load, function () {
                        clearTimeout(timeOut);
                    })
                    .one(click + ' ' + event_cleanup, stop);
                $box.removeClass(className + "off").addClass(className + "on");
                timeOut = setTimeout(publicMethod.next, settings.slideshowSpeed);
            };

            stop = function () {
                clearTimeout(timeOut);
                $slideshow
                    .text(settings.slideshowStart)
                    .unbind([event_complete, event_load, event_cleanup, click].join(' '))
                    .one(click, function () {
                        publicMethod.next();
                        start();
                    });
                $box.removeClass(className + "on").addClass(className + "off");
            };

            if (settings.slideshowAuto) {
                start();
            } else {
                stop();
            }
        } else {
            $box.removeClass(className + "off " + className + "on");
        }
    }
```

what do i have to change here. thanks for any suggestion or help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't change anything there. You are likely getting that error because you are doing someone on your end that is removing the settings data.  Show what you are doing, not snippets of code from the plugin.

Comment: bdw thanks @jack solved it.hab been mixing things up so remained confused. bdw thanks for your suggestions.